# A few c questions: static methods, arrays

Tags: c, arrays, static

I am working on a project in C and have stumbled upon a few questions that I hope you fine folks can help me with! The project is just manipulating coordinate points that the user creates via standard input. I've included the different files and their functions below;

```
//points.h
struct Point{
   int x;
   int y;
}

//reads points from stdinput into our points array
int pointReader(struct Point points[]);

///////////////

//points.c
void pointReader(struct Point points[]){
   //points[] is originally empty array (filled with NULLS)
   struct Point point;
   char buffer[10];
   printf("X Coordinate:");
   fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
   point.x = (int)buffer;
   printf("Y Coordinate:");
   fgets(buffer, 10, stdin);
   point.y = (int)buffer;
   append(points, point);    
}

static void append(struct Point points[], struct Point point){
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      if (points[i] == NULL){
         points[i] = point;
}
```

Upon compilation, I am receiving the following errors and I'm not too sure why:

```
points.c:115:10: error: invalid storage class for function 'append'
points.c: In function 'append':
points.c:127:17: error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'struct Point' and 'void *')
```

Also, can I so easily 'toss' around the `points[]` array like I am attempting to do?

Thanks for any comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error is *most likely* because you haven't declared the function `append` before you call it. Add a function prototype before you call it. In other words, before the `pointReader` definition, add the following line:

```
static void append(struct Point points[], struct Point point);
```

The second error is because the values in the `points` array are *not* pointers, and can therefore not be treated like pointers (like comparing it to `NULL`). You have to use another method of checking if an entry in the array is used or not. For example using the `x` and `y` values of `-1` or something similar.

---

You also have another problem, and that is that you can't convert a string to an integer by just casting. You have to use a function such as [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) for that:

```
point.x = (int) strtol(buffer, NULL, 10);
```

Comment: Ok, so perhaps just populating each index of the array with 0 initially and then checking for the 0 would work?

Comment: @FrankyJ542 Unless `0` are valid values then yes.

Comment: Understood Joachim, thank you very much for your help. Any comments on my manipulation of the array of points? I hope what I am trying to do is clear enough!

Comment: @FrankyJ542 There's another problem with your code as well, I updated my answer about it. Otherwise it looks okay.